# highcharts column chart with 2 series and dynamic labels

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts, series

I have a web page with a few drop down lists where the users pick what they want, then click "show chart" and the chart loads based on what they selected.

I'm building a forecast vs actual report, so I want a column chart with 2 series and the labels should be dynamic based on what's returned from the database. I'd like the chart to look like the one below, but instead of 0,5,10, etc...it should be products as returned from the query and the goan and actual are 2 separate series.

Can someone please provide an example of this.  I'm using json/jquery.

Comment: we can't see the reference chart you have provided.

Comment: unfortunately I can't include the reference because i'm new to this board.  To clarify, my query returns 2 values per category.  one is goal and one is actual.  like this:  auto loans  100 150 credit cards 200 300  mortgages 1000 1500.  so I want the chart to show the categories on the x axis and plot 2 graphs.  one for the goal numbers and one for the actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain methods provided by highcharts so that you can do changes to the chart on the fly.

one such method is Update(). this can be used with axis as well as series

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({
    categories: [new set of categories],
    linecolor: "new line color",
});
```

with this you can not only change the categories but also change the xAxis properties on the fly.

```
chart.series[0].update({
    name: "new Name",
    date: ["new data"]
});
```

you can change the series properties including the data from here.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qnqxLdbm/) I've worked out a sample example for you.